# It's possible switchover a innodb cluster instance as primary?

Tags: mysql, innodb, failover, mysql-innodb-cluster, failover-cluster-instance

If I am in topologyMode Single-Primary, it's possible to switchover the primary instance between machines in the cluster? I did not find anything in the documentation.

Ie: in my lab I have:

```
topology": {
            "mysql0:3306": {
                "address": "mysql0:3306",
                "memberRole": "PRIMARY",
                "mode": "R/W",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE",
                "version": "5.7.42"
            },
            "mysql1:3306": {
                "address": "mysql1:3306",
                "memberRole": "SECONDARY",
                "mode": "R/O",
                "readReplicas": {},
                "role": "HA",
                "status": "ONLINE",
                "version": "5.7.42"
```

How to switch `mysql1` as primary?

**Update:**

Seems to have the command `cluster.setPrimaryInstance()` but it did not work in MySQL 5.7, only 8.0. So, there isn't a way to do it in MySQL 5.7?